# unregister imq broker from cluster properly

Tags: connection, glassfish, openmq

I am currently trying to manage an openmq cluster (with glassfish 3.0.1) and I encounter some strange behavior.

The cluster work for seven months now without any problems with 2 broker registered.

I now need to add two other broker in the cluster temporarily. Here is what I have before:

```
-------------------------
Host         Primary Port
-------------------------
localhost    7676

Cluster ID                    MyCluster
Cluster is Highly Available   true

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                          ID of broker       Time since last 
 Broker ID         Address               State         Msgs in store   performing takeover   status timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Broker1         192.168.0.1:7676    OPERATING           5                                     6 seconds
Broker2         192.168.0.2:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
```

Then, I successfully start two other broker on two other server and I got:

```
-------------------------
Host         Primary Port
-------------------------
localhost    7676

Cluster ID                    MyCluster
Cluster is Highly Available   true

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                          ID of broker       Time since last 
 Broker ID         Address               State         Msgs in store   performing takeover   status timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Broker1         192.168.0.1:7676    OPERATING           5                                     6 seconds
Broker2         192.168.0.2:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
Broker3         192.168.0.3:7676    OPERATING           5                                     6 seconds
Broker4         192.168.0.4:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
```

The application run well with the configuration, automatically using the two new brokers. The problem occurs when I stop a broker from the cluster using the following command:

`./imqcmd shutdown bkr`

on one of the server. The result of `./imqcmd list bkr` is the following:

```
-------------------------
Host         Primary Port
-------------------------
localhost    7676

Cluster ID                    MyCluster
Cluster is Highly Available   true

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                          ID of broker       Time since last 
 Broker ID         Address               State         Msgs in store   performing takeover   status timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Broker1         192.168.0.1:7676    OPERATING           5                                     6 seconds
Broker2         192.168.0.2:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
Broker3         192.168.0.3:7676    TAKEOVER_COMPLETE   0                 Broker1             6 seconds
Broker4         192.168.0.4:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
```

Everything seems to be ok, takeover is performed by Broker1, but when I look at the server.log of the glassfishs, I found the following line :

`[C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [192.168.0.3:7676]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused|#]`

Like if the glassfish try to connect to the shuted down broker.

Is there something I missed ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing command line was:

```
imqdbmgr remove bkr -n Broker3
```

```
then a list will ouput:

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                          ID of broker       Time since last 
 Broker ID         Address               State         Msgs in store   performing takeover   status timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Broker1         192.168.0.1:7676    OPERATING           5                                     6 seconds
Broker2         192.168.0.2:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
Broker4         192.168.0.4:7676    OPERATING           8                                     6 seconds
```

the Broker3 is no more registered in the broker HA cluster.